# Is it okay to contact an agency model directly?

Tags: models

Is it poor etiquette to contact a model, who is already represented by an agency, directly about doing a photoshoot together?

Particularly if there is no agency contact info in their Instagram bio.

Comment: Not quite sure why the downvote there?

Comment: @JamesSnell, just a guess, and not a downvoter, but maybe because this isn't directly about photography?  I know it is related, and probably on topic, but not everyone would see it that way.

Comment: I presume this is to wopk with them rather than sign them?

Comment: @CrazyDino Yes. Updated the question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No. It is fine. That is pretty much how things work. A model provides contact information for them to be contacted. You send a brief description of what you have in mind and they will let you know how to proceed from there.

Models do not necessarily do all their modelling under a single agency unless they have an exclusive agreement and even that it may be for a subset of modelling (commercial fashion for example) but it is possible for them to do gigs for artwork without an agency or perhaps with a different one.

Should they want you to pass through an agency, they will respond with the necessary contact info for you to do so.

Answer (score 6):

If the contact information provided on their Insta is their own and they don't list an agency contact then that's effectively the only way you have to contact them and clearly it's the one they prefer.

The worst that can happen is they refer you to their management to book and make arrangements.